# clear hibernate cache of specific domain class

Tags: hibernate, grails

Imagine i have following class:

```
class Test {
   String name    
   static mapping = {
      cache true
      version false
}
```

The goal would be to insert rows using native sql on the database level so hibernate wouldn't recognize those changes. how can i notifiy hibnerate about this new rows?

Is there something like -> Test.clearCache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though it's a deprecated way, it's shorter and still works.

```
def sessionFactory // inject Hibernate sessionFactory
sessionFactory.evict(clazz, id)
// or evict all class instances:
sessionFactory.evict(clazz)
```

Documentation is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html), see it for the up-to-date way with `Cache`.

Answer (score 8):

This answer is a little bit old... the evict method is deprecated... you can use

```
sessionFactory.cache.evictEntityRegion(Class.name)
```

this worked for me...  just google the class and you will find all methods...

Comment: sessionFactory.cache.evictEntity(entity.getClass(), entity.ident())