# Change DB value at runtime

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I'm using grails 3.1.9 and MySQL DB.
I have a domain with a String field that contain a short description.
Sometimes I need to change it straight from the DB, I know it's not the best practice, but for now I have no choice.
I see that the change is to taken at run-time, even if I log out and log in again, I use Spring security. If I restart the tomcat service then of course it works.
I assume there are some cache policy in gorm to speed up the experience, do you know if there is a way to avoid it?

**UPDATE**

I'll force to clear the cache of a particular domain. I still have to test it, see this link 
[clear hibernate cache of specific domain class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625515/clear-hibernate-cache-of-specific-domain-class#13198858)

**UPDATE/2**

I try to invalidate/clear second level cache and it works, here the code:

```
 Map<String, ClassMetadata> classesMetadata = sessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata();
        for (String entityName : classesMetadata.keySet()) {
            println("Evicting Entity from 2nd level cache: " + entityName);
            sessionFactory.evictEntity(entityName);
        }
```

Comment: There is no such cache in a fresh new Grails application. You need to explicitly configure Hibernate second level cache to obtain that behaviour. Did you configure it? If so, you can either configure this domain class to not be cached or you can add way to clear the cache in your system so you could use that after you do your change in the DB.

Comment: thanks! it would be good to a way to clear the cache once in  a while when needed

Comment: ```
        CacheManager.ALL_CACHE_MANAGERS.each { CacheManager mgr ->
            mgr.getCacheNames().each {
                mgr.getCache(it).removeAll()
                log.info "Cleared cache $it"
            }
        }
```